# Python: progressbar for fitting an HMM model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, progress-bar

I am training quite a large Hidden Markov Model using hmmlearn and I would like to see the progress of fitting the model, since it takes quite a lot of time. My code to fit the model looks as follows:

```
model = hmm.GaussianHMM(n_components=vocab_size, covariance_type="full")
model.start_prob_ = np.array(frequency_list)
model.transmat_ = np.array(transitions)
integer_array = integer_array.reshape(-1,1)
model.fit(integer_array)
```

So I would like to see the progress of the `model.fit(integer_array)` line.
Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try setting `hmm.GaussianHMM(n_components=vocab_size, covariance_type="full", verbose=True)`, this should make the fitting process verbose.

If you want to have more information, there is a monitor for convergence, an example is [here](https://hmmlearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#monitoring-convergence).